# Different Image Slider

Tags: jquery, css

I know there are lot of sliders out there that i can download and use,but i cant find one that i need.I need simple slider that will move back and forward but it needs to display 6 images per slider in formation 3*2 :

[3*2 slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYb8m.png)

This is my html code:

```
<ul>

        <li><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg1.jpg" alt=""><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg3.jpg" alt=""><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg5.jpg" alt=""><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg6.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg7.jpg" alt=""><img class="galleryimg" src="newimages/galleryimg8.jpg" alt=""></li>

    </ul>
```

So is out there any slider like this one ?

If tags are wrong please change them,Ty and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [slick js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Then you just need to use the grid mode.